# Install boto without password

Tags: password, sudo, git

I am new to Ubuntu. I have a virtual box on a Windows 7 computer.

I went to this page. https://github.com/boto/boto

I need to install boto.

The commands are

```
$ git clone git://github.com/boto/boto.git
$ cd boto
$ python setup.py install
```

However, after I enter the first line I get

```
[sudo] password for user:
```

However, I do not have a password.

How can I run the commands?

I need a simple explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in to a cloud instance with a shared key - you can likely prefix the last command with sudo:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

alternatively, you can install boto from the built-in package management system, with the command

```
sudo apt-get install python-boto
```

while the latest version is not part of the apt-get package system, it will be likely current enough for most needs.

If you installed Ubuntu from CD or image, you entered in a password for the 'ubuntu' user during setup.   That is the password you should use.   If you have forgotten it and can't guess it - the easiest approach to to re-install, recovery is a bit of an advanced effort and it may be faster/easier/better for you to start over.

Comment: The issue that `python setup.py install` requires `sudo` password (which seemed to be the case) no longer is an issue (as of commit 5e318b19cc87479dba3ebb273a51723108a2abe7), i.e. the command fails with `Permission denied` error as expected.

Comment: I guessed as much but I didn't pull the source - thanks Karl for confirmation.